# Protobuf map type JSON format uses string literal "key" and "value" not the actual values

Tags: java, json, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am trying to convert a protobuf object to JSON format using `com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat` but the `map` type came out unexpected.

My message is like this

```
message Response {
   repeated Candidate candidates = 1;
   map<string, ErrorMessage> errors = 2;
}

message ErrorMessage {
   string message = 0;
   ErrorType type = 1;
}

enum ErrorType {
   ERROR = 0;
   WARNING = 1;
}
```

The issue is the JSON format of the `Response` object I created

```
Response response = ...
Return new ResponseEntity<>(new JsonFormat().printToString(response), HttpStatus.OK);
```

I expect the errors be formatted as a map keyed by the string value (of the map key)

```
...
"errors": {
  "someID" : {
      "message": "blah blah",
      "type": "ERROR"
  }
}
```

However the **actual** output is (I evaluated only the `new JsonFormat().printToString(response)` part in intellij)

```
...
"errors": {
  "key": "someID",
  "value": {
      "message": "blah blah",
      "type": "ERROR"
  }
}
```

I hope it's some small configuration I missed to make protobuf (or Jackson?) to be aware of the actual key value ? not using "key" and "value".

BTW, what's the point of having literal "key" and "value" field in a `map` type ? You can't do constituent lookup with it and you might just use a custom type/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfectly for me:

*test.proto*

```
syntax = "proto2";
package by.dev.madhead;
option java_outer_classname = "SO";

message Candidate {

}

enum ErrorType {
    ERROR = 0;
    WARNING = 1;
}

message ErrorMessage {
    required string message = 1;
    required ErrorType type = 2;
}

message Response {
    repeated Candidate candidates = 1;
    map<string, ErrorMessage> errors = 2;
}
```

*App.java*

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
        SO.Response response = SO.Response.newBuilder()
            .addCandidates(SO.Candidate.newBuilder().build())
            .addCandidates(SO.Candidate.newBuilder().build())
            .addCandidates(SO.Candidate.newBuilder().build())
            .putErrors("error1", SO.ErrorMessage.newBuilder().setMessage("error1").setType(SO.ErrorType.ERROR).build())
            .putErrors("error2", SO.ErrorMessage.newBuilder().setMessage("error2").setType(SO.ErrorType.WARNING).build())
            .build();

        System.out.println(JsonFormat.printer().print(response));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{
    "candidates": [{
    }, {
    }, {
    }],
    "errors": {
        "error1": {
            "message": "error1",
            "type": "ERROR"
        },
        "error2": {
            "message": "error2",
            "type": "WARNING"
        }
    }
}
```

Which has no `key`s and `value` as you see. Make sure that you printed not the message itself, but the result of `JsonFormat.printer().print()`. Basically, `key` and `value`s you've seen are from internal `toString()` implementation of Protobuf `Message`.

And the full class name for `JsonFormat` is `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat`, not `com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat`.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Indeed I used `com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat` instead of `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat` which was the issue. The googlecode one seems to be an out of date formatting util ?

Comment: I guess, yes, it's outdated. All Google results refer to `com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat`.